# She kicked me in the "sac" or "sack"? Reference is to the testicles

Tags: orthography, slang

How do we spell "sac" / "sack" when referring to the testicles?

Is it: She kicked me in the "sack" or "sac"?

Comment: Normally, in the US, it would be "in the balls".

Comment: I have pondered this many times... I'm sure I've used both spellings also.

Answer (score 2):

*Sack* is short for *nut sack* or [*nutsack,*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nutsack) meaning the scrotum.

(In case it needs spelling out, the allusion is to a bag containing *nuts,* i.e. testicles.)

A word spelled *sac* also exists, which [Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sac) defines as

> A cavity enclosed by a membrane within a living organism, containing air, liquid, or solid structures.

The latter spelling is mainly used in a life-science context.

Comment: One might also note that the scrotum *is* a sac in the life-science sense.

Answer (score -2):

All due respect, Mr. Kowal, but I have always spelled it *nutsac*. (And apparently, Coolio, and other artistes of of his genre, agree.)

I have also learned (in researching this particular question) that there is apparently a sport called disc-golf (which really shouldn't surprise me because I went to a hippie college where the only sport was "freestyle frisbee" and the school colors were *heliotrope* and *puce*, which are two very similar shades of purple) and the purveyors of a special bag for carrying the equipment (frisbees) for said sport have appropriated the name "NutSac", but failed to register the trademark - leading to the conclusion that too many others regularly use it for another purpose.

Regarding the question, I submit that *sac* is less ambiguous.

Comment: The Google Ngram tool doesn't align with your preference, regardless of which corpus you pick: [<1>](http://tinyurl.com/qcun9gz), [<2>](http://tinyurl.com/qgvbxf3), [<3>](http://tinyurl.com/onnrlsk) or [<4>](http://tinyurl.com/q7glnbu). (I have disregarded those English-language corpuses which returned no results at all.)

Comment: In my favorite fractured French: "No hitting below the belt" it's spelled zac. See. Honore de Balzac.